# How to avoid error when a macro package is included multiple times in ca65 assembler

Tags: ca65

Using the .MACPACK directive, predefined macro packages can be included in the assembler source code with `.macpack name`. For example `.macpack generic` defines macros like add, or sub (see https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#macropackages).
However, including the same macropackage twice throws an error, because the respective macros are already defined. This problem is sometimes difficult to avoid when a package is included again via a different file.

I tried to put a wrapper around the `.macpack` command like this:

```
    .ifndef add      ;checking if the add macro is already defined
    .macpack generic
    .endif
```

but that did not work because the `.ifdef` / `.ifndef` don't trigger on macro definitions. Any ideas on how I could protect the macro package from double use? The macro package itself is part of the cc65 suite, so I don't want to change it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR: Use `.DEFINEDMACRO` to check for a macro being defined

---

`.IFNDEF` is a short hand for `.IF .NOT .DEF[INED]` (*1). `.DEF[INED]` looks up assembler symbols, i.e. any identifier that works like a label. The name of a macro is not a an assembler symbol but a macro identifier, handled like a build in CPU mnemonic, but managed in a separate table of macro names, which can be searched by `.DEFINEDMACRO`.

`.DEFINEDMACRO` can be found under *Pseudo Functions* in [section 10.8](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#ss10.8), right after `.DEF[INED]`. With `.MACPACK`its application might look like this:

```
        .if     .not .definedmacro(add)
                .macpack generic
        .endif
```

---

In addition macro identifiers can be found exactly like CPU mnemonics by `.ISMENM[ONIC]` if the `.FEATURE ubiquitous_idents` is set (see [11.41](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#.FEATURE)) to allow redefining CPU mnemonics (*2). It's described in [section 10.12](https://cc65.github.io/doc/ca65.html#ss10.12) of the CA65 documentation. In fact, the very example used there is about defining a macro only if not defined already.

---

*1 - Obviously added to help C-addicts to have a less hart time when breaking free and discovering the beautiful world without :))

*2 - I usually set this as default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, but I tried it out (ca65 V2.19) and it seems that .ismenemonic also cannot detect a macro identifier. The example in Section 10.12 does not work if the same code is pasted twice, it throws a "Macro is already defined" error on the second part.

Comment: @PeterB. Oops, my fault, I got always enabled that macros can replace instructions.  But no prob, use .DEFINEDMACRO instead - stands in the manual right after .DEFINED in the manual :)) I'll correct that.

Comment: .definedmacro works perfectly, thanks for your quick and competent help!